# Error Expected identifier or (

Tags: objective-c, c, plugins, unity-game-engine

Hi Guys i am stuck in a problem **Expected identifier or (** following is the code in .h file

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "HelloWordPlugin.h"

    extern "C"   //Error Expected identifier or (
    {
        void _displayUIAlertViewWithTitleAndMessage(const char* title, const char* message);
    }

    NSString* CreateNSString(const char* string);
    char* MakeStringCopy(const char* string);
```

I have added their definition in .mm file,
I am unable to find the actual problem, Please advise

Comment: This is code snippest of header file, I have added definition of these methods in .mm file

Comment: I have removed this line #import "HelloWordPlugin.h" and all its dependencies from class but still problem exists

Comment: Unity3D can't be programmed in Objective-C, can it?

Answer (score 8):

As I understand it `extern "C"` is not meaningful in Obj-C, just as it is not meaningful in plain C. You should remove the `extern "C"` since you already have C linkage.

If you want your code to compile as C++ then you will need `extern "C"`, but wrapped in `#ifdef __cplusplus` so that the Obj-C compiler does not see it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this style in both your header and body implementation:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
 void _displayUIAlertViewWithTitleAndMessage(const char* title, const char* message);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```